# SVN: PROPFIND request failed

Tags: svn, ant

build.xml is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="AUTO_BUILD">

   <property environment="env"/> 
   <path id="svnant.classpath"> 
      <fileset dir="C:\Program Files\Java\apache-ant-1.8.1/lib"> 
         <include name="**/*.jar"/> 
      </fileset> 
   </path> 
   <taskdef resource="svntask.properties" classpathref="svnant.classpath"/>

   <target name="checkout"> 
      <svn username="username" password="password"> 
         <checkout url="Repo-URL" destPath="C:\Program Files\Java\apache-ant-1.8.1\test"/> 
      </svn> 
   </target>
</project>
```

I have added svnant.jar, svnClientAdapter.jar, svnjavahl.jar and commons-lang-2.0.jar to ANT_MOME\lib.
Now I am running checkout target from windows XP command prompt:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\apache-ant-1.8.1>ant checkout
```

Getting the below error:

```
Buildfile: C:\Program Files\Java\apache-ant-1.8.1\build.xml

checkout:
[svn] Using command line interface
Svn : Checking out a working copy from a repository :
co -r HEAD https://c..../trunk C:\Program Files\Java\apache-ant-1.8.1 --username 6044
28101 --password ******* --non-interactive
svn: PROPFIND request failed on '/svn/asia-pac-financials/trunk'
svn: PROPFIND of '/svn.../trunk': Could not resolve hostname `col.com':
The requested name is valid and was found in the database, 
but it does not have the correct associated data being resolved for. (https://col.com)

BUILD FAILED
C:\Program Files\Java\apache-ant-1.8.1\build.xml:16: Can't checkout

Total time: 1 second
```

Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says that it `Could not resolve hostname 'col.com'`.

Can you make sure that you can reach the server `'col.com'` (ping maybe?)